# Use deface to render partial and add object, variable or locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I am using Deface to override a spree view and I need to render a variable.

Like this: `<%= render 'image_tab_partial', :type => 'vintage'%>`

Using Deface:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/admin/products/index", 
                     :name => "example-3",
                     :insert_after => "div#pdf_file_name", 
                     :partial => "image_tab_partial")
```

I am able to render this partial but how to render `:type => 'vintage'` with Deface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/admin/products/index", 
                     :name => "example-3",
                     :insert_after => "div#pdf_file_name", 
                     :text => "<%= render 'image_tab_partial', :type => 'vinatge'%>")
```

You could also render a partial which renders your image tab partial with the type specified.

Comment: So I used rendering a partial which renders partial with type specified just wanted to confirm if there is no way to specify objects or strings with the deface ':partial =>' ..... that is why I decided to post question ....

Comment: If there is already a partial tag than using above two approaches feels like a hack ... :| ....

Comment: You are correct that deface doesn't currently have support for specifying additional parameters to the Deface partial.